# How to rename files, removing everything after a certain character, but adding a suffix (reset count on prefix change)

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with files named like this:

```
b56-m7s - 300_m_f.jpg
```

I need to delete every character after and including the " -" so that the new name would be:

```
b56-m7s
```

The problem is that several files would end up with the same name, so I was hoping to add a simple ascending suffix. Also, optimally, the ascending suffix resets every time the basename of the file changes. like for example:

```
b56-m7s(1)
b56-m7s(2)
b5j-i89(1)
b5j-i89(2)
```

etc.

This is how i imagine some of the code but i don't know how to add the ascending suffix

```
 get-childitem *.jpg | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(^[^ -]*, "") }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution, edited so the count restarts on every prefix change.  You might make that more clear in the question.  I've provided an ideal example.

```
get-childitem *.jpg | 
foreach {
  $prefix = $_.basename -replace ' - .*'
  if ($prefix -ne $oldprefix) { $i = 1 } # also true the first time
  rename-item $_.fullname "$prefix-$i.jpg" -whatif
  $i++
  $oldprefix = $prefix
}

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\js\foo\b56-m7s - 300_m_f.jpg Destination: C:\users\js\foo\b56-m7s-1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\js\foo\b56-m7s - 300_m_g.jpg Destination: C:\users\js\foo\b56-m7s-2.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\js\foo\c56-m7s - 300_m_f.jpg Destination: C:\users\js\foo\c56-m7s-1.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\js\foo\c56-m7s - 300_m_g.jpg Destination: C:\users\js\foo\c56-m7s-2.jpg".
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. It kinda works but optimally I would like $i to return to 1 whenever a the start of the filename changes so you would have files named:
`b56-m7s-1.jpg`
`b56-m7s-2.jpg`
`m45-23-1.jpg`
`m45-23-2.jpg`
`m45-23-3.jpg`
etc.

Comment: thank you - this worked brilliantly. I did a few modifications so that it doesn't matter what type of file it is since some of my files are jpg and some are tif and png. (I know i should have clarified that in the question) If you're interested i just added this variable `$fileext = $_.Extension` and changed the new name to `rename-item $_.fullname "$prefix-$i$fileext"`. Again thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Close, but you'll want to make sure to match on the preceeding space as well to remove that, and you'll want to make sure to include the extension.

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Foreach-Object {
    $currentFile = $_
    $renamed = $false
    $count = -1
    while(-Not $renamed){
      $newName = $currentFile.Name -replace '(\s+-.*)*\..*', ''
      if( ++$count -gt 0 ){
        $newName += "(${count})"
        Write-Output "Using name: ${newName}"
      }
      try {
        Rename-Item $_ "${newName}$($currentFile.Extension)" -EA Stop 2>$null
        $renamed = $true
      } catch {
        if( $_.Exception -match "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." ){
          Write-Warning "Filename ${newName}$($currentFile.Extension) exists - incrementing filename"
        } else {
        Write-Error $_
        $renamed = $true # set renamed to true because some other error occurred on this file, continue to the next one
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically we match on the expression above using the `-replace` operator, and replace it with an empty string. The `"$()"` allows us to evaluate an expression within the string and return a rendered string with the computed value as opposed to just referencing a variable which you can do with `"$var"` or "${var}". We do this twice - once for the file name, and then again to restore the extension from the original file object since the `-replace` ends up removing the extension from the new name.

### Explaining the regex

- `\s` matches on any whitespace character
- `+` matches on one or more of the preceeding character
- `-` in this case is a literal `-` character
- `.` matches on any character
- `*` matches on zero or more of the preceeding character
- `\.` is a literal `.`. We need to match on this for the extension.
- `()` signifies a group. Think of it like a subexpression. You can match on a group with quantifiers (such as `+` or `*`) as if it were a single character.

So to break down the expression above we optionally match on `one or more whitepace characters` (note that `*` after the group) followed by a single `-` followed by `zero or more additional characters`. Then we definitively match on the extension, because we want that removed from the new name (it gets re-added in `Rename-Item`).

### EDIT

I missed the second part where you wanted to increment the filename if it already exists. I can't think of an easy way to do it but I wrote some code that should work for you. It basically attempts the rename, and if it fails due to the file already existing, it will attempt again and increment the counter. Note that adding the increment did add complexity to the code.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but I can't get it to work :) Firstly there's a "$" missing on line 12 and somewhere there's a "}" missing. With those two characters added to the code, it does rename one of each name-type, i.e. 'b56-m7s - 300_m_f.jpg' gets renamed to 'b56-m7s' but if the next couple of names will end up with an identical name, it skips then which means that the part of the code that is meant to add the incrementing suffix does not work :)

Comment: I see where I botched it, I'll fix it this morning even I'm not on mobile

Comment: thanks a bunch, and no rush, I'm just happy that you're helping :)

Comment: There, the main issue with why the rename kept attempting was that I was never incrementing `$count` unless it was greater than 0. I made a couple of changes to fix that as well as the missing bracket and the `$` missing before `true`.